# Shared service not working ,giving different kind of behaviour

Tags: angular, typescript

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'aditya';

  constructor(private service : HeroService)
  {}
  sender()
  {
    this.service.addchanges("ab");
    this.service.addchanges("cd");
    this.service.addchanges("ef");
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h3 (click)="sender()">Click me to send the value</h3>
<app-detail></app-detail>
```

hero.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {

  constructor() { }

  area = new Subject();

  changeemitted = this.area.asObservable();

  addchanges(change)
  {
    console.log("entered at service");
    console.log("chnage getted",change);
    this.area.next(change);
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DetailComponent } from './detail/detail.component';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   DetailComponent
 ],
 imports: [
   BrowserModule
  ],
 providers: [HeroService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.css']
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private serviceFetcher:HeroService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  caller(){
    console.log("caller entered");
    this.serviceFetcher.area.subscribe(text => console.log("text detail",text));
  }
}
```

detail.component.html

```
 <p (click)="caller()">
 detail works!
 </p>
```

Well actually my all service is working but the problem is that
when ever i m calling the sender() ,click event use on the text, my value are going to service and are getting stored too.

```
hero.service.ts:19 entered at service
hero.service.ts:22 chnage getted ab
hero.service.ts:18 ___________________________
hero.service.ts:19 entered at service
hero.service.ts:22 chnage getted cd
hero.service.ts:18 ___________________________
hero.service.ts:19 entered at service
hero.service.ts:22 chnage getted  ef
```

But after that when i call the caller(),click event use on the text, present in detail.component.html
subscribe method is not getting called ,on console only caller entered is displayed.
      detail.component.ts:22 caller entered
      detail.component.ts:29 ___________________________
But after that without refreshing i again call the sender(),click event use on the text, then my value goes and subscribe method is also get called,

```
  hero.service.ts:19 entered at service
  hero.service.ts:22 chnage getted ab
  detail.component.ts:23 text detail ab
  hero.service.ts:18 ___________________________
  hero.service.ts:19 entered at service
  hero.service.ts:22 chnage getted cd
  detail.component.ts:23 text detail cd
  hero.service.ts:18 ___________________________
  hero.service.ts:19 entered at service
  hero.service.ts:22 chnage getted  ef
  detail.component.ts:23 text detail  ef
```

i tried to put debugger and check but its visible there but the "text detail" is visible . is this any kind of Subject behaviour?
can you guyz tell mi where i m going wrong ,i am new in angular just trying to explore it more. Even if its small mistake then let mi know instead of closing the form.
i want to get the data when i am calling the caller() method.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you want to get updates from `area` whenever `sender()` function is called right?

Comment: no when caller() is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should not subscribe to an observable again and again, it will result it memory leak.

```
    private subscription: Subscription; // unsubscribe it onDestroy

    caller() {
        if (!this.subscription) {
            this.subscription = this.serviceFetcher.changeemitted.subscribe((text) => {
                console.log(text);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: subscribe to an observable again and again means click on button multiple time..??

Comment: was that error because i was directly subscribing to area instead of changeemitted..??

Comment: @adityatoke yes clicking again on the button will subscribe it again without checking it.

Comment: cant we do like this means once we send data in pipe and then as per our requirement we subscribe it..?

Comment: actually i m new in angular so asking lots of questions  ,but does creating variable of subscription means we are subscribed.?

Comment: Not sure if we can get previous updates with subjects! But you can maintain an array with all updates if you really want it.

Comment: when you call a subscribe function, you get subscribed, after a subscription you will start getting updates if someone called that <observable>.next(data).

Comment: Ohk thanks bro for helping me,your code worked for me

Comment: nice to hear that :)